# multiprocessing in python (selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

*Trying to run each stock at the same time. Pretty new to coding. Can't seem to iterate through webpages or run at once. I hope someone knows. Thank you. it would work if I could open many web pages at once or if I could use multiprocessing to run many pages at once. I think that is what I need. It seems that to run through multiprocessing would be simpler code. I end up with a circular process error with the current.

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as Ec
from  selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
import concurrent.futures
from multiprocessing import Pool








stocks=('TSLA','3M', 'American Express', 'Amgen', 'Apple', 'Boeing', 'Caterpillar',
'Chevron', 'Cisco Systems','Coke', 'Disney', 'Dow', 'Goldman Sachs', 'Home Depot',
'Honeywell', 'IBM', 'Intel', 'Johnson & Johnson', 'JP Morgan Chase','McDonald’s', 'Merck',
'Microsoft', 'Nike', 'Procter & Gamble', 'Salesforce', 'Travelers', 'UnitedHealth', 'Visa',
'Walgreens', 'Walmart')


def run_stocks(stocks):
    for s in stocks:
        s=(" ")
        path= r"C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
        driver=webdriver.Chrome(path)
        driver.get(("https://www.tradingview.com//{}").format(s))
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)



        sign_in= driver.find_element_by_link_text("Sign in")
        sign_in.click()
        driver.implicitly_wait(3)
        sign_in=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='tv-signin-dialog__social tv-signin-dialog__toggle-email js-show-email']")
        sign_in.click()
        driver.implicitly_wait(3)
        Username=driver.find_element_by_name("username")
        Username.click()
        Username.clear()
        Username.send_keys("")
        sign_in= driver.find_element_by_name("password")
        sign_in.click()
        sign_in.clear()
        sign_in.send_keys("")
        sign_in.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        """Logining in
        """
        time.sleep(2)
        Charts= driver.find_element_by_link_text("Chart")
        Charts.click()
        time.sleep(1)
        close_popup=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='close-button-3pxNR2uR closeButton-1H9ESDGF']")
        close_popup.click()

    for s in stocks:
        search_stock= driver.find_element_by_id("header-toolbar-symbol-search")
        search_stock.click()
        type_stock= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Search']")
        type_stock.click()
        type_stock.clear()
        """searching for charts and in the chart for any stock youd like
        """
        type_stock.send_keys(("{}").format(s))
        time.sleep(.5)
        type_stock.send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
        time.sleep(.5)
        type_stock.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

        time.sleep(2)




        #switch_to_line= driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]")
        #switch_to_line.click()
        #widescreen= driver.find_element_by_id("header-toolbar-fullscreen")
        #widescreen.click()

        view_range= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='apply-common-tooltip'][contains(text(),'1M')]")
        view_range.click()
        """time range change
        """

        driver.save_screenshot(("C:\stocks\{}.png").format(s))
        #driver.get
        #take photo




        switch_to_line= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='header-toolbar-chart-styles']/div[1]")
        switch_to_line.click()

        

        action= ActionChains(driver)
        action.key_down(Keys.ALT).send_keys("t").key_up(Keys.ALT)
        action.perform()
    
        

    #//*[@class='apply-common-tooltip'][contains(text(),'5D')]
    """for when i want to switch """








        #graph= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='drawing-toolbar']/div/div/div/div/div[1]/span[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/span/svg")
        #graph.click

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(processes=2)
    p.map(run_stocks, stocks)
```

Comment: You'd want to use multithreading with Selenium, also driver.implicitly_wait(5) sets a default wait once during the lifetime of the driver. No need for them and time.sleep() use webdriver waits.

Comment: Yes. That's a good point. Thank you.